# Expand a div to full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and jQuery. I have a div on my page right now that is 500 x 400 and it is sitting inside of a bootstrap row and col div. for example:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div id="myDiv"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I want to use jQuery to tell this div to go full screen. When I click on my button to make it go full screen it seems to be locked inside of the bootstrap row and goes to 100% x 100% inside of the parent div. Is there anyway to tell #myDiv to eject from the parent that it is in and go full screen.

My css:

```
 #myDiv{
    z-index: 9999; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
 }
```

Comment: `.myDiv` would select an element with the class of myDiv. Your div has the ID of myDiv so to select it you would use `#myDiv`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7nzy6w6/1/)

CSS

```
#myDiv.fullscreen{
    z-index: 9999; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
 }

#myDiv{background:#cc0000; width:500px; height:400px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div id="myDiv">
           my div
          <button>Full Screen</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    $('#myDiv').toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
});
```

The trick is in setting `position:fixed`, by toggling the `.fullscreen` class. This takes it outside of the normal dom tree, so to speak, and sizes/positions it relative to the window.

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: This was for me a nice way to work around the fact that google maps on IOS does not allow full-screen.. With a little bit of this and that for the event handling and ios detection combined with toggling this class works like a charm!

Comment: Been looking everywhere for this. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**JQuery**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#myDiv').css({"top":"0","bottom":"0","left":"0","right":"0"});
});
```

**CSS**

```
 #myDiv{
    z-index: 9999; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
 }
```

There is a little error in your css. Change the `.` to `#`.

Comment: @Ted 's solution is also pretty neat.